# Visual Studio 2015 colors of tabs changed

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have trivial problem. I reinstalled my VS2015 and now when I open up my old solution I get other colors than few days ago( theme is the same ).

[image: Colors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably installed Productivity Power Tools, which does change the tabs to another color groups.

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/34ebc6a2-2777-421d-8914-e29c1dfa7f5d

Comment: Ohhh. That's the reason thanks. Now I changed options of Power Tools and it is working good

Answer (score 5):

go to Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools >  Custom Document Well > General

and uncheck  color tabs by project
in French : tools means outils